# Modify a php variable with a dropdown to generate different amounts of SQL results

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql, sql-server

I have a form that queries a SQL database with a stored procedure and generates TOP 100 results. I would like to put a dropdown box next to the search button to choose how many results to display.

I imagine doing this by running a different stored procedure for each amount (i.e. TOP 100, TOP 200, TOP 300 etc.) so I want to change the $query variable being executed by the 'Search' button to run each of these stored procs.

Can PHP do this or do I need javascript/AJAX?

Example of my code:

```
echo '<input class="btn btn-primary btn-lg active" type="submit" name="search" value="Search">    <br><br>';

$query = "EXEC dbo.sp_HeaderSearch100";
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: AJAX will of course be better because PHP will make the page to load again and user would definitely not like it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with the basic POST.

Your markup would look like:

```
<input type="text" name="amount" /> <!-- or select/option with the same name, etc. -->
<input type="submit" class="..." name="search" />
```

Then your backend would process it simply as:

```
// Use an array of available "top" procs
// Otherwise use a default (e.g. 100)
$top = in_array($_POST['amount'], array(100, 200, 300)) ? $_POST['amount'] : 100;
$query = "EXEC dbo.sp_HeaderSearch$top"
```